# Decide the type of collection for Java small desktop application

Tags: java, oop, dictionary, object-oriented-analysis

I need to understand something for a homework at OOP course.
The objective is to simulate a small bank application.And I am confused at this part : "Implement the class Bank using a predefined collection which uses a hashtable. The hashtable key will be generated based on the account main holder."
So HashTable, HashSet and HashMap having   are good to use.
Yet, can I also use TreeMap or TreeSet? I founded that java.util.TreeMap works in the same way. They even have same method put , remove etc.
To sum up , should I use only classes having "Hash" or can I use also the others like TreeMap?

Comment: There is quite a big difference between a set and a map.

Comment: I know that . But am I restricted to use a certain collection? Or what kind of collection do you think I should use based on the problem statement

Comment: Consider it a learning experience: try implementing it with one; then try changing the code to use the other, and see what the difference is. If you use `Map` or `Set` in your code everywhere except where you actually create instances (e.g. `Map<Key, Value> map = new HashMap<>()`), it is a simple matter of changing the `HashMap` to `TreeMap` in those places.